Sum Over Min Die
You have been tasked to find the expected value of a die game in which you are rolling
2 dice at a time. Your first roll of the dice will all be summed up and will be your starting score. Your next, and final, roll of the
2 dice will be your divisor, in which you are going to pick the optimal die out of the two to divide your total by, which will be your final score.
Calculate the expected value of playing this game optimally
MY approach -
I first got the expected sum on 1st roll which is 7.
Then I calculated the expected value of min(d1,d2) on 2nd roll and by evaluating that i got the value 91/36.....(I have verified it)
now to get the max expected return I did -
Max Return = Expected Initial score/Expected number you choose on 2nd roll
Max return = 7/(91/36) = 36/13 but it is wrong ??
Can anyone correct me where i went wrong and suggest the correct approach

This is an application of the ratio distribution $f(Z)$, $Z=X/Y$.
You are looking for $\mathrm{E}\left(X/Y\right)$. Here, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, thus:
$$
\mathrm{E}(X/Y)=\mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{E}(1/Y)
$$
Note that $\mathrm{E}(1/Y)\neq 1/E(Y)$!
$E(X)=7$ as you have shown already. As $Y$ is the minimum of the points of a throw of two fair dice, its probability mass function is
$$
f(Y= k)=\frac{13-2k}{36}
$$
The expectation $\mathrm{E}(1/Y)=\sum_i \frac{1}{i}f(Y=i)$ is
$$
\mathrm{E}(1/Y)=\frac{1}{1}f(1)+\frac{1}{2}f(2)+\cdots+1/6f(6)=\frac{397}{720}
$$
Hence, $E(Z)=7\times \frac{397}{720}$
